# Using percent sign in EJS

Tags: json, node.js, ejs

I'm having difficulties getting my code to run.

I'm importing a JSON object `alkodata`, which is parsed from a `.xlsx` file.

It contains a `alkodata.alkoholi-%` object.

The problem is that node throws a

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in C:\filepath\something.ejs while compiling ejs"

error because of the percent sign in the Json-object.

Does EJS have a escape character to prevent this?

```
<% include ./partials/header.ejs %>

<h1>Tänne tulee mun about AlkoAppo sivu!</h1>
<h2><%= message %></h2>

<% for(var i = 0; i<10; i++) { %>
    <p>nimi: <%= alkodata[i].nimi %> </p>  
    <p>Hinta: <%= alkodata[i].hinta %>e </p> 
    <p>Vahvuus: <%= alkodata[i].alkoholi-%  %> </p>
<% } %>

<% include ./partials/footer.ejs %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your key value has a character like that then I would suggest using the bracket syntax to access your property:

```
<% include ./partials/header.ejs %>

<h1>Tänne tulee mun about AlkoAppo sivu!</h1>
<h2><%= message %></h2>

<% for(var i = 0; i<10; i++) { %>
    <p>nimi: <%= alkodata[i].nimi %> </p>  
    <p>Hinta: <%= alkodata[i].hinta %>e </p> 
    <p>Vahvuus: <%= alkodata[i]['alkoholi-%']  %> </p>
<% } %>

<% include ./partials/footer.ejs %>
```